Transaction is getting reverted on calling bookRoom() function
I'm deploying my contract by passing these constructor params:
(["Hotel Red","Hotel Radisson"],[1,2],[12,13],[3300000000000000,3500000000000000],[12,13])

The contract is getting deployed successfully.
But, when I'm calling the bookRoom() function with these params:
1, 2, 1713042515, 1713062515

Then, it's getting reverted with this message:
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "Insufficient balance in your account".

Here’s my contract code:
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Hotel {
    address payable public owner;

    struct Room {
        uint256 price; // in wei
        uint256 discount; // in percentage
        uint256 roomID;
        uint256 hotelID;
        uint256[] entryTime;
        uint256[] exitTime;
    }

    struct BookedRoom {
        address payable user;
        string status;
        uint256 roomID;
        uint256 hotelID;
        uint256 entryTime;
        uint256 exitTime;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => mapping(uint256 => Room)) public hotels;
    mapping(address => BookedRoom[]) public myBookings;

    constructor(
        string[] memory _name,
        uint256[] memory _hotelID,
        uint256[] memory _roomID,
        uint256[] memory _price,
        uint256[] memory _discount
    ) {
        require(
            _name.length == _hotelID.length &&
                _hotelID.length == _roomID.length &&
                _roomID.length == _price.length &&
                _price.length == _discount.length,
            "lengths not equal"
        );
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _name.length; i++) {
            hotels[_hotelID[i]][_roomID[i]] = Room({
                price: _price[i],  // in wei
                discount: _discount[i],
                roomID: _roomID[i],
                hotelID: _hotelID[i],
                entryTime: new uint256[](0),
                exitTime: new uint256[](0)
            });
        }
    }

    function bookRoom(
        uint256 _hotelID,
        uint256 _roomID,
        uint256 _entryTime,
        uint256 _exitTime
    ) external payable {
        Room storage room = hotels[_hotelID][_roomID];
        require(
            checkAvailability(_hotelID, _roomID, _entryTime, _exitTime),
            "Room is not available for the given slot"
        );

        uint256 pricePerHour = ((room.price * (100 - room.discount)) / 100) / 24;
        uint256 hoursBooked = (_exitTime - _entryTime) / 3600;
        uint256 toPay = pricePerHour * hoursBooked;
        require(msg.value >= toPay, "Insufficient balance in your account");

        address payable user = payable(msg.sender);
        user.transfer(toPay);

        room.entryTime.push(_entryTime);
        room.exitTime.push(_exitTime);

        myBookings[msg.sender].push(
            BookedRoom({
                user: user,
                status: "Booked",
                roomID: _roomID,
                hotelID: _hotelID,
                entryTime: _entryTime,
                exitTime: _exitTime
            })
        );
    }

    function cancelBooking(
        uint256 _hotelID,
        uint256 _roomID,
        uint256 _entryTime,
        uint256 _exitTime
    ) external payable {
        require(
            block.timestamp <= _entryTime,
            "Can not cancel after entry time"
        );

        Room storage room = hotels[_hotelID][_roomID];
        require(room.entryTime.length > 0, "No bookings for this room");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < room.entryTime.length; i++) {
            if (
                room.entryTime[i] == _entryTime && room.exitTime[i] == _exitTime
            ) {
                room.entryTime[i] = 0;
                room.exitTime[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < myBookings[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            if (
                myBookings[msg.sender][i].roomID == _roomID &&
                myBookings[msg.sender][i].hotelID == _hotelID &&
                myBookings[msg.sender][i].entryTime == _entryTime &&
                myBookings[msg.sender][i].exitTime == _exitTime
            ) {
                myBookings[msg.sender][i].status = "Cancelled";
                break;
            }
        }

        uint256 refundAmount = (_exitTime - block.timestamp <= 2 days)
            ? (msg.value * 9) / 10
            : msg.value;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(refundAmount);
    }

    function checkAvailability(
        uint256 _hotelID,
        uint256 _roomID,
        uint256 _entryTime,
        uint256 _exitTime
    ) public  view returns (bool) {
        Room storage room = hotels[_hotelID][_roomID];
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < room.entryTime.length; i++) {
            if (
                _entryTime < room.exitTime[i] && _exitTime > room.entryTime[i]
            ) {
                return false; // Overlapping time slot found, room is not available
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }

    function withdrawFunds() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only owner can withdraw funds");
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getBookingDetails() external view returns (BookedRoom[] memory) {
        return myBookings[msg.sender];
    }
}


Can you add the exact constructor args that you’re passing, resulting in the revert?

Sure, (["Hotel, Grand","Hotel Red"],[1,2],[12,13],[3300000000000000,3300000000000000],[12,13])

It's working fine for me when I tested on local VM network of Remix IDE. Is it reverting in your case on Remix only?

Please share all the screenshots with me , it is not working in my local remix ide or hardhat project.

Can you share the link of a screen-recording using Loom or so, showcasing your interaction with the Remix IDE while deployment?

brother, give me your email or whatsapp to share the mp3 file

Are you unable to upload it on Loom? It should allow a 15 minutes screen recording for free, and then you can share the generated url.

yes, it is not taking upload.

Then, can you upload on Google Drive and share the link ?

sure , here is the link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2E-qBmc434AOKDiemdGwK0LWgb8CAuy/view?usp=sharing

I've added the answer. Please check.

It's reverting when calling the bookRoom() function because you're not passing in sufficient value. The msg.value should be greater than or equal to toPay, as specified in this require() function::
require(msg.value >= toPay, "Insufficient balance in your account");

To determine the accurate value to pass, you can add a function to calculate the toPay value, like this:
function getValueToPay(
        uint256 _hotelID,
        uint256 _roomID,
        uint256 _entryTime,
        uint256 _exitTime
    ) external view returns (uint256) {

        Room storage room = hotels[_hotelID][_roomID];

        require(
            checkAvailability(_hotelID, _roomID, _entryTime, _exitTime),
            "Room is not available for the given slot"
        );

        uint256 pricePerHour = ((room.price * (100 - room.discount)) / 100) / 24;
        uint256 hoursBooked = (_exitTime - _entryTime) / 3600;
        uint256 toPay = pricePerHour * hoursBooked;
        return toPay;
    }

This will return the value that you can pass as Wei, in the value parameter.
Based on the parameters passed for DEPLOY and bookRoom(), it's calculated as 605000000000000.


In this case, if you pass 605000000000000 as the VALUE in Remix IDE and then call the bookRoom() function, the transaction will be successful.


Brother , what is this value field ? what is its purpose? and lastly how should I deploy my contract through hardhat for project purpose ? Do I have to pass the value field in deploy.js?

The value field in Solidity represents the amount of native token (in wei units) sent with a function call or transaction.

You don't need to specify value while deployment, but while calling a particular function that is payable i.e., that is expecting some value to be passed.

Brother,one more help please. This is my github repo for blockchain backend :
https://github.com/ZeeshanDEVPRO/MyHotel-DAPP/tree/main/blockchain             I am unable to book a room in frontend , even after having 2 sepolia ETH .The console error is insufficient balance. Kindly help! My deployment command is: npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia

I've created a pull request by fixing the calculation of priceAsValue  using entryTimeUnix and exitTimeUnix while calling the getFinalPrice() function.

Thank you so much bro

You’re welcome. Happy to help.
